# Deleting entries from @CollectionTable with @ElementCollection using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have an entity like the following. It is simplified as I cannot post the original code but it should be sufficient to get the idea.

The point is:

Using an `EntityManager` I can delete entries in the `my_table` table. So far so good. Now I also need to delete entries in `my_mapping_table` but I don't have any idea how to do that.

Using the above `EntityManager` probably won't work because this field is not an `Entity`.

Any ideas how I can delete entries from that table or truncate it?

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyTable {

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = SomeClass.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "my_mapping_table", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_1", referencedColumnName = "id_2"))
    @Column(name = "someclass_enum")
    @Convert(converter = SomeClassConverter.class)
    private Set<SomeClass> setOfSomeClass = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ElementCollection` is managed through its parent entity. To remove them , you have to get its parent entity first and then simply clear the collection.

First create a method on MyTable to clear all of its ElementCollection :

```java
@Entity
public class MyTable {

    public void removeAllSomeClass(){
          this.setOfSomeClass.clear();
    }
}
```

To delete all ElementCollection for a particular MyTable record :

```java
MyTable row1 = entityManager.find(MyTable.class,1);
row1.removeAllSomeClass();
```

So to truncate all entries from `my_mapping_table` :

```java
for(MyTable tbl : em.createQuery("from MyTable", MyTable.class).getResultList()){
  tbl.removeAllSomeClass();
}
```